# Prevent clients from retaining pointers returned by a C++ class

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics

I have a `file_manager` class that tracks the files in a given directory. I use it as the model for a file UI similar to Windows Explorer or macOS Finder. The `file_manager` has various `find()` methods to allow clients to ask for handles to files, and those methods return an `optional` which will be empty if no files matched that search criteria.

Since files can be deleted from the directory at any time without our knowledge, there's a comment on the `find()` methods saying that you shouldn't retain the pointers they give you. Instead, you should just query the `file_manager` again later (e.g., once per frame/once per UI update/etc.). This rule helps prevent having to wrap every future use of the `file_handle` in something like an `is_still_on_disk()` check.

Here's what the code currently looks like:

```
struct file_handle {
    std::string path;
    std::string contents;
    // Other metadata here
};

class file_manager {
public:
    file_manager(std::string directory_to_manage);

    // Clients shouldn't retain this pointer, because the file could
    // disappear from disk at any time.
    // Empty if we were unable to find a file with this name.
    optional<const file_handle *> find_file_by_name(std::string file_name) const;
    optional<const file_handle *> find_file_modified_before(time_t time) const;
    // other find_xxx() methods here

    // Examines the disk to add/remove from all_known_files to match the
    // current state of the directory.
    // Only called at well-defined times, from the same thread that uses
    // the "find" methods.
    void update();

private:
    std::list<file_handle> all_known_files;
}
```

Is there any way to codify this "do not retain" rule such that you'd get a compile error (or failing that, a runtime assertion failure) if you stored the return value of the "find" method as a member variable? (Preventing it from being a static variable would be nice too, if possible.)

That is, I'd like to be able to have the `file_manager::find_xxx()` methods instead return an optional "un-retainable" wrapper... something like this:

```
class file_manager {
    . . .
    optional<cant_retain_me<file_handle>> find_file_by_name(std::string file_name) const;
    . . .
}
```

...where the `cant_retain_me` wrapper would allow this code to work:

```
void do_stuff() {
    auto optional_file = my_file_manager.find_file_by_name("foo.txt");
    if(optional_file.has_value()) {
         cant_retain_me<file_handle> handle = *optional_file;
         // use handle as though it were a normal file_handle or file_handle *
    }
}
```

...but would break this code:

```
class client {
    client() {
        auto optional_file = my_file_manager.find_file_by_name("foo.txt");
        if(optional_file.has_value()) {
            my_handle = *optional_file;
        } else { /* use some fallback value */ }
    }

    void do_stuff() {
        // Try to use my_handle as though it were a normal file_handle or file_handle *
    }

    cant_retain_me<file_handle> my_handle;
}
```

Two ideas I had considered for the wrapper:

- Prevent the wrapper class from being instantiated on the heap. This would help a little (it's better than nothing!), but doesn't prevent the use shown in `client` above.
- Make the wrapper class move-only (`delete` the copy constructor). I *think* this would work, in that it would at least force clients to write some very awkward code to store the handle as a member... but I don't write much code with explicit moves, so I'm not entirely sure if this would have the desired effect.

I realize in a language with `memcpy()` there's never going to be a way to fully prohibit clients from bad behavior, but I'd like to make it misusing the API as obvious a code smell as possible.

Comment: That seems like a very poor way to abstract a file system.  Provide handles that can be to not-a-file, notifications of what handles are no longer files, and use monadic patterns/algebraic composition to make checking if a file is still existing not to be a pain.  Frame based "file is gone" seems... honestly toxic.

Comment: Why not just use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`? Use `std::shared_ptr` for objects inside your manager, and let clients retain `std::weak_ptr` references to them. If the objects get freed, the `weak_ptr`s will get nulled, which clients can test for before accessing the objects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I did not know about `std::weak_ptr`! Interesting... that sounds like that I'm looking for.